# File Upload by docker container

Tags: docker, spring-boot, dockerfile

I have a spring boot app. Docker container has no permission to create a file.

#### docker file:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine

VOLUME /tmp

ADD /build/libs/file-upload-service-2.0.0.jar app.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

#### Image Build Command:

```
docker build -t file-upload-service .
```

#### Image Run Command:

```
docker run -d --name file-upload-service -p 9104:9104 file-upload-service:latest
```

#### Folder Permissions:

```
sudo chown -R  root:docker  /home/storage/

sudo chmod -R 777 /home/storage/
```

When running with `java -jar` then the application can create the file.

Comment: What exception do you get when you try to create the file/folder?

Comment: File file = new File(path);
 file.canWrite() return false

Comment: And what is the value of the `path` variable? Is it `/home/storage`?

Comment: /home/storage/sajib.png

Comment: Ok. You're expecting this file to be picked up from your host machine. Whereas, the code is trying to locate the file within docker container. You'll have to mount the host machine volume to make it work.

Comment: Lemme write an answer to explain this.

Comment: Hi @GolamMazidsajib I am trying to achieve the same things, but none of the explanation worked for me, for some reason, I have 400 error and `MissingServletRequestPartException: Required request part 'file' is not present`, this is only happening in docker and I have root user, do you have a clue ? Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Problem

You're expecting your code inside the docker container to locate a file in your host's filesystem. A docker container is a fully contained(as the name suggests) runtime environment with its private filesystem, network, etc. You can not directly access the host's filesystem from your docker container **unless** you have some requisite configurations (mounting) in your `docker run ..` command or the compose file.

### Solution

You'll have to mount the volume `/home/storage` inside the docker container to read/write from/to that location from within the container. To do so, after changing the filesystem permissions in your host (which you have already), use the following run command to start the container:

```
docker run -d --name file-upload-service -v /home/storage:/home/storage -p 9104:9104 file-upload-service:latest
```

The `-v` flag in the above command tells docker to mount the `/home/storage` directory of the host machine (the left side of `:`) to the `/home/storage` directory of the container (the right side of `:`). You can change these directories according to your use case.